# Why release a property that you've already set to nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Here are two methods in a view controller from an Apple tutorial:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.eventsArray = nil;
    self.locationManager = nil;
    self.addButton = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [eventsArray release];
    [locationManager release];
    [addButton release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Couldn't the `dealloc` method be shortened to the following?  If not, why not?

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [managedObjectContext release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`- (void)viewDidUnload` is not guaranteed to be called, so you should always release things in dealloc too.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285932/when-is-uiviewcontroller-viewdidunload-called) to find out when it's called, and what you should do when it is.

Answer (score 3):

No, because you cannot rely on `viewDidUnload` being called upon deallocation. `viewDidUnload` is only called when the view controller receives a memory warning while its view is not on screen. If the view controller gets deallocated, `viewDidUnload` is not called (AFAIK, I'm not entirely sure).

Answer (score 1):

because it's a good practice to always cleanup your ivars in dealloc. something could go wrong, or you may encounter an execution you do not expect.

Answer (score -1):

Setting `eventsArray` to `nil` just means it has no content, but still space for content
Calling `[eventsArray release]` releases the space the array consumed.

Comment: Not really. If `eventsArray` is a retain or copy property, setting it to `nil` effectively releases the backing object (if any).