# Why would you set-to-nil AND release a property of a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, memory-management, properties, uiviewcontroller, dealloc

There's something I don't get in Apple documentation. Here's an extract from the -(void)viewDidUnload of the UIViewController class :

> your dealloc method should release
>   each object but should also set the
>   reference to that object to nil before
>   calling super.

If you use a retain and a synthetize for a xxx attribute in your code, why do most of Apple examples do a set-to-nil in viewDidUnload :

```
self.xxx = nil;
```

but recommands to do both a set-to-nil AND a release in the dealloc :

```
[xxx release];
self.xxx = nil;
```

Why is the set-to-nil not enough for the dealloc ?

ps : i know my question is very similar to this one ["Why release a property that you've already set to nil?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090427/why-release-a-property-that-youve-already-set-to-nil) but it's not strictly the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[xxx release];
self.xxx = nil;
```

This is wrong as xxx will get released twice, recommended way is release iVar and set it to nil, not using property:

```
[xxx release];
xxx = nil;
```

The reason for not just using

```
self.xxx = nil;
```

is that calling setter method may have some side effects that may cause problems in dealloc method (i.e. use some other iVar that may be already deallocated)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Does it mean that if one is 100% sure there is no side effect in the setter method (for instance when the synthetized one is not overriden), we can use self.xxx = nil as the only call to release memory ?

Comment: we can, but there's still small chance that setter implementation will change in future and introduce side effects... but in most cases self.xxx = nil should work fine