# does an entry in Instruments "leaked block" during application running imply memory leak?

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks, xcode4, instruments

does an entry in Instruments "leaked block" during application running imply memory leak?

That is, if one is half way through using the iPhone application, where you might have some variables that have been retained but it hasn't got to the part of the application where it gets released, then do these show up as leaked blocks or not?

If the answer is that variables which have not been finished with do show up here as leaked blocks, then this would be quite confusing then if you are stopping/pausing instruments, in which case how would one run instruments in a manner whereby any leaked blocks you see are valid memory leaks?  (e.g. need to kill application to end everything first and then look at instruments?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A leak in Instruments indicates that Instruments cannot find a pointer to the allocated memory starting at any of a group of "root" pointers. Specifically, from the [Memory Usage Performance Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html):

> The Leaks instrument records all allocation events that occur in your application and then periodically searches the application’s writable memory, registers, and stack for references to any active memory blocks. If it does not find a reference to a block in one of these places, it deems the block a “leak” and displays the relevant information in the Detail pane.

So retaining something is not a leak as long as you have a pointer to it in one of your ivars, local variables or static variables. But there are ways that the Leaks instrument can get confused, and sometimes Apple has a leak in their frameworks, and sometimes Instruments has a bug.

The thing you're looking for with Leaks are steady and significant increases in the amount of leaked memory either over time or when doing specific actions. Tiny, one-time leaks are generally not worth chasing.

Answer (score 2):

You should split leak testing into logical units, be it view based or functionalities based. Start from the beginning, test your initial view thoroughly, fix issues, move to next view and so on. I recommend running static analyzer before testing for leaks.

Comment: thanks - in terms of my specific question, the recent testing I've been doing today seems to be suggesting at any time during the running of the profiler, if there is an entry in the leaked blocks table this implies a real leak, however I'm not 100% sure of this - this is what I was hoping to confirm...

Comment: @Greg Lets say you're doing intensive calculation which takes 5 minutes to finish while profiling with instruments. If at 30 second mark instruments indicate a memory leak - that's it, you're probably leaking an object. That means you didn't manage your objects properly and at that 30 sec mark, not a single object has reference to leaked object anymore or rather: the last object that knew about leaked object somehow lost it's memory address/location and noone can find it anymore. Maybe the last object released leaked object properly but another object forgot to.

Comment: @Greg If you stop instruments at 2.5 minute mark, objects allocated and deallocated before that time don't exist anymore. If during that time single object resides in memory, and no other object knows about it, that's a leak. Of course, you can always do something like alloc+init object, save it's memory address into file (@"%p", object) and retrieve it 15 minutes later. Instruments will probably tell you the object is leaking because you hidden reference from instruments. Not sure why would you do anything like that in a first place... you can try though, see how Instruments react :)

Comment: @Greg Anyway, I hope I explained thing or two but carefully read @Rob Napier's answer, there's lots to learn from it and it's also the correct answer. I'd say your question is wrong :)